# AWS Mobile analytics

Tags: android

I am very new to AWS. I created one android Application and I want know app Analytics form Amazon console for that I integrated Amazon App Id but I did not get get any overview or graph information. How can get all the details and overview graph.

Answer (score 0):

https://console.aws.amazon.com/mobileanalytics/home/

Go here and then click on dashboard.